# servlet java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParseException

Tags: google-app-engine, jackson, twilio

I Am integrated Twillio SMS API in my Java web application hosted in Google App Engine. So I also have the purchase account Of Twillio, so I want to store receiving SMS in my database so that why I already written a code and so I already included all Jackson Jar library File(jackson-core-asl ,jackson-mapping) in my project. But this exception remains the same:

[image: Please Click To Check Exception Image]

> Uncaught exception from servlet java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParseException at
>   com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestResponse.getParser(TwilioRestRespon‌​se.java:226)
>   at
>   com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestResponse.toMap(TwilioRestResponse.j‌​ava:244)
>   at
>   com.twilio.sdk.resource.ListResource.parseResponse(ListResou‌​rce.java:212)
>   at com.twilio.sdk.resource.Resource.load(Resource.java:53) at
>   com.twilio.sdk.resource.ListResource.getPageData(ListResourc‌​e.java:196)
>   at
>   com.twilio.sdk.resource.ListResource.iterator(ListResource.j‌​ava:70)

Comment: Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParseException
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestResponse.getParser(TwilioRestResponse.java:226)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestResponse.toMap(TwilioRestResponse.java:244)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.ListResource.parseResponse(ListResource.java:212)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.Resource.load(Resource.java:53)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.ListResource.getPageData(ListResource.java:196)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.ListResource.iterator(ListResource.java:70)